# should I set ViewHolder class variable as instance variable in adapter?

Tags: android, instance-variables, android-viewholder

I'm not sure how to explain let's see the code first

```
public class myBaseExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
    private GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;//here?
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
    private class GroupViewHolder {
        TextView groupText;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.expand_list_group, null);
            groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
            groupViewHolder.groupText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_expand_group);
            convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
        } else {
            groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class myBaseExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private class GroupViewHolder {
        TextView groupText;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
        GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;//or here?
/*-----------------------------------------------*/
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.expand_list_group, null);
            groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
            groupViewHolder.groupText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.txt_expand_group);
            convertView.setTag(groupViewHolder);
        } else {
            groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
    }
}
```

for the variable "GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder"
it is okay to set it as instance variable?

which one is correct(or better) and why?

Comment: The second one, because it have been made sepecificly for each row.

Comment: Oh ...I figure it out thanks!